# How to cancel a jump while mid-air in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to cancel my jump using a key input with my `CharacterController` but have been having some issues figuring out the right way to do it. I am using standard and very simple controller code and the jump code itself is one line.

I have tried to add a bool `isInAir` inside both my falling and jump code and then use that to cancel my jump but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
float jumpHeight = 10f;
float gravity = -9.81f;
bool isInAir = false;

void Update()
{  
    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0) // falling
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
        isInAir = false; // turns false while actually touching the ground
    }

    if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump))
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity); 
        isInAir = true; // turns true while in air only
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
    { 
        isInAir = false;
    }

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

What should happen is if I press jump and my character is in the air, pressing the relevant key would then instantly make my character stop and fall to the ground. So if I am doing a running jump, my character would still instantly stop the jump and fall even if my player is currently in the process of jumping forward but I haven't been able to solve that yet.